# Dilemma concerning prediction of user satisfaction

Tags: machine-learning, probability, sample, bayesian-network, marketing

Imagine that you have data with information about users : Age, sex, location, etc ... with the answer to two additional questions : Q1 = Have you tried product P ? yes/no ; Q2 = Did you enjoy product P ? yes/no

Q2 is not asked to the user when answer to question Q1 is No.

example :

Tom;42;male;San Fransisco; .... ;YES;NO

Jenny;27;female;Detroit; .... ;NO;?

Donald;72;male,Washington;....;YES;YES

...

Intuitively, we can imagine that an user that would enjoy a product is more likely to have tried it than another user.

With that data set, I can learn the probability model for a user to have tried product P given what I know about him. I can also learn the probability model of product P satisfaction given the fact that the user has tried it.

But, can I also learn somehow the probability that a user that have not tried the product P will enjoy it ?

## Addition

We are testing a very simple model with 3 boolean variables : Sex,Try,Satisfaction. We will create a hypothetical model with an additional variable : Interest. That model would be a bayesian network where Interest is   conditionally linked with Sex and Try and Satisfaction are conditionally linked with Interest.
With hat model we will generate samples. We will remove the Satisfaction values from that samples when Try is set to No.
With that sample set, we will learn model and see whether we can learn the same joint distribution on Sex,Try and Satisfaction.
We can learn with only those 3 variables or impose the structure of the model that generated the data (with the Interest variable that is unrecorded).
My guess is that in the second case, we will find back the same model that generated the data but not in the first case. What do you think ?

Comment: I think thats not possible, since you have no information about enjoyment of people who havent tried the product yet. So there is no data to train a model. What you could try is to train a model using all the participants who have tried the product to predict enjoyment based on sex, location, age... But this could be dangerous because, just as you've said allready, the group of tried and the group of not tried could differe systematically regarding to liking the product. So the question for me would be: Is it suitable to assume that not tried participants are compareable to tried participants?

Comment: You are probably right. Anyway, I am curious about parameter learning with a structure that forces the model to comply with our causal intuition. I added something in my original post in that regard.